# Symfony 4 - Class Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType not found

Tags: php, symfony

Trying to do file upload by documentation:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html

I have pasted the code:

```
// src/Form/ProductType.php
namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Product;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;

class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            // ...
            ->add('brochure', FileType::class, array('label' => 'Brochure (PDF file)'))
            // ...
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Product::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

And getting error

> Class Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType not found in
>   E:\projektai\php
>   projektai\htdocs\mokomieji\symfony_4_demo\config/services.yaml (which
>   is loaded in resource "E:\projektai\php
>   projektai\htdocs\mokomieji\symfony_4_demo\config/services.yaml").

I see PhpStorm giving warning already that AbstractType is not found. What is wrong here, how to fix?

composer.json:

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/console": "^4.0",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.0",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "^4.0",
        "symfony/lts": "^4@dev",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
        "symfony/orm-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "^4.0",
        "symfony/validator": "^4.0",
        "symfony/yaml": "^4.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/dotenv": "^4.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install --symlink --relative %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "id": "01C1AMZG7RRHZQ87EJYRTRWDDA",
            "allow-contrib": false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the dependency onto `symfony/form` is missing? A quick look at the packages you listed and their dependencies lets me suspect this...

Answer (score 3):

Did you run `composer req form`? Now Symfony4 comes as minimal package. Everything what was built-in in the previous versions, now you have to install via composer. You can do this on two ways. First as before using /package or using alias. Whole list of aliases you can find on [symfony.sh](https://symfony.sh/).

So if you didn't install forms you can do this using

```
composer req form
```

or

```
composer req symfony/form
```